# How to show the background color from bottom of the circle using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a circle figure to monitor the level of charging. But the % of charge shown is from top -down approach rather than bottom - up approach.
Please let me know how do I make this charging look from bottom to top?

```js
function move(width) {
    if (width > 0 && width <= 100) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBarid");
                    
        if (width <= 100) {
            if (width < 25) {
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
                elem.style.height = width + '%';
            } else if (width < 45) {
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fc9b25";
                elem.style.height = width + '%';
            } else if (width < 70) {
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#f4f442";
                elem.style.height = width + '%';
                            
                //  elem.style.clip = "rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px)";
            } else {
                elem.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
                elem.style.height = width + '%';
            }

            elem.style.position = width + '%';
        }

        elem.innerHTML = width + "%";
    }

    return width;
}
```

```css
.myBar {
  /*width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:50px solid #ff3;
  border-radius:100px;*/


  width: 215px;
  height: 215px;
  line-height: 100px;

  text-align: center;
  border: 8px groove ;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: center;
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="move(80)">
    <div class="myBar" style="align-content:center">
      <div id="myBarid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Circle graph depicting the level of charging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi8uC.png)

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox can easily fix this:

```js
function move(width) {
  if (width > 0 && width <= 100) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBarid");


    if (width <= 100) {
      if (width < 25) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        elem.style.height = width + '%';
      } else if (width < 45) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fc9b25";
        elem.style.height = width + '%';
      } else if (width < 70) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#f4f442";
        elem.style.height = width + '%';

        //  elem.style.clip = "rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px)";
      } else {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
        elem.style.height = width + '%';
      }
      elem.style.position = width + '%';
    }
    elem.innerHTML = width + "%";
  }
  return width;
}
```

```css
.myBar {
  width: 215px;
  height: 215px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 8px groove;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: center;
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  /* added */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body onload="move(80)">

  <div class="myBar" style="align-content:center">
    <div id="myBarid">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```